# Android : Import strings from Excel to res/strings folder

Tags: android, string, excel, android-studio-2.0

I need to import a huge dump of strings (around 4k) into res/strings folder, is there any simpler way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: Excel don't have much columns. It contains just a single column of strings.

Comment: Well Excel could be saved as xml, the rest is with Notepad++, some replace, mark and delete unnecessary lines.